# Convert HEX to 4 digit integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am trying to convert a HEX string to 4 digit integer. I can change by the following command but I do not want to generate random integer value every time if same HEX string is passing. The integer number must be same. This is not happening in my case:

```
const reqq = crypto.createHash('md5').update(admin.companyName).digest('hex');
let valueNum = parseInt(reqq, 16);
let resultValue =  Math.floor(Math.random(valueNum) * 9000);
admin.companyID = resultValue;
console.log(resultValue);
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: why using Math.random() ? To get the corresponding INT it will suffice parseInt()

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Oh yes, Thanks . Didn't thought that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to convert the hex hash to a decimal number is correct. If you do not want a different `companyName` to lead to a different hash, you can remove the random call in `resultValue`. You can verify your hex conversion is correct by using a [converter](https://justquickmath.com/hex_to_dec/)